# unpredictable behahviour of list view item's checkbox click

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview, getview

In a list view I am using `checkboxes` to select list list item, when `checkbox` is check then the background of the `listview` item should changed, but when I click `checkbox` of first item it's background changes but when I scrolls down list item 3's background and `checkbox` state change also. I don't get it why this happening may be due to listview's recycling process.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tvTitle, tvCat, tvDate;
        CheckBox cbAddSummary, cbAddPhoto,cbItemSelect;
        Log.i("mponeList:position",String.valueOf(position));
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mp_one,parent,false);
            tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            tvCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat);
            tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            cbAddSummary = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_summary);
            cbAddPhoto = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_photo);
            cbItemSelect = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_item_select);
        }

        tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tvCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat);
        tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        cbAddSummary = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_summary);
        cbAddPhoto = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_photo);
        cbItemSelect = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_item_select);
        cbItemSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    View row = ((View) buttonView.getParent());
                    if (isChecked) {
                        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_mp_list_item_check);
                    } else {
                        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_mm_er_list);
                    }
                }
        });


        MpOneListModel model = this.list.get(position);
        tvTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
        tvCat.setText(model.getCat());
        tvDate.setText(model.getDate());

        return convertView;
    }
```

It's the code I am using in `getview` of the adapter.

Comment: Yes exactly it is due to recylcing to Listview whenever u scroll .....

Comment: @koutuk how to avoid that

Comment: *it is due to recylcing to Listview* - *how to avoid that* --> By reading about ListView recycling ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two methods in your adapter

```
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return list.size() + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep that checked state in your model (MpOneListModel). Update that model onCheckedChanged

```
cbItemSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    View row = ((View) buttonView.getParent());
                    if (isChecked) {
                         model.setChecked(true)
                    } else {
                         model.setChecked(false)
                    }
                }
        });
```

then add your logic

```
if(model.isChecked()) {
    //update background
} else {
    //reverse background
}
```

Currently when you scroll down. **your previous views is using again according to the list view recycling**. so you should better keep your state in model itself

Answer (score 0):

Add isChecked boolean property in your model and initialize it with false and use following code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     {
    TextView tvTitle, tvCat, tvDate;
    CheckBox cbAddSummary, cbAddPhoto,cbItemSelect;
    Log.i("mponeList:position",String.valueOf(position));
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mp_one,parent,false);
        tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tvCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat);
        tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        cbAddSummary = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_summary);
        cbAddPhoto = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_photo);
        cbItemSelect = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_item_select);
    }

    tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    tvCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat);
    tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
    cbAddSummary = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_summary);
    cbAddPhoto = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_add_photo);
    cbItemSelect = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_item_select);

  final MpOneListModel model = this.list.get(position);
    tvTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
    tvCat.setText(model.getCat());
    tvDate.setText(model.getDate());


    cbItemSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                View row = ((View) buttonView.getParent());
                model.isChecked = isChecked;
                if (isChecked) {
                    row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_mp_list_item_check);
                } else {
                    row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_mm_er_list);
                }
            }
    });



    if(model.isChecked){
        cbItemSelect.setCheck(true);

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that list view reuse your views. In getView method you should check is current item checked. One of variants to do it - in adapter you can add ArrayList and add there elements that is checked. Here is example

```
MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<Model> list;
private ArrayList<> selectedList;

public MyAdapter(List<Model> items) {
this.list = items;
selectedList = new ArrayList(items.size);
}

getView(...) {
...init view here
final Model item = list.get(position);
checkBox.setChecked(selectedList.contains(item));
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if (isChecked) selectedList.add(item);
else selectedList.remove(item);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain position of the list item inside onCheckedChanged() method. Also use ViewHolder pattern. Refer [this](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html). It covers both.